# Weird Python __import__ behavior

Tags: python, python-import

I have been looking in the following for quite some time, without being able to figure out what is going on.

I am working with an existing Python project and I have a directory structure like the following (simplified):

```
.
├── functions
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── file1.py
│       ├── file2.py
│       └── file3.py
├── myexec.py
└── mylib.py
```

I have the following code in the `__init__.py` file of the `functions` module (among other code, within a function):

```
module_files = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
[__import__("functions.test." + module) for module in module_files]
```

The weird thing is that in the following lines, the name `test` is used and Python does not complain about it, even though there isn't anywhere any import of `test`.

I have put some diagnostic messages before and after the two lines above and I saw that `globals()` gets updated with the `test` module.

Please note that the `__init__.py` of `test` is empty.

What could be going on here? Is there any possibility that the `__import__` behavior has been changed somehow and lead to the `test` name be imported when importing `functions.test.fileX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the import system loads `functions.test.file1`, it needs to set up the attribute chain that lets the expression `functions.test.file1` not produce an AttributeError. That means that

```
__import__('functions.test.file1')
```

has the side effects

```
functions.test = <the test module object>
functions.test.file1 = <the file1 module object>
```

Since the `functions` package's `__init__.py` uses the `functions` package's attributes as its global variables, global variable lookup for the name `test` now finds `functions.test`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This explains why that happens. Especially the last sentence. Cheers.